# Java binarySearch return is being ignored

Tags: java, return, binary-search

So as the title suggests, I am writing some code to perform a version of a binary search in Java. However, my return statements are ignored and the function instead returns the last "catch all" return statement as shown below:

```
    public int binarySearch(int min, int max) {

        int mid = ((min+max)/2);
        double[][] m1 = createFilledSquareMatrix(mid);
        double[][] m2 = createFilledSquareMatrix(mid);
        double[][] m3 = new double[mid][mid];
        long time = analyzeMultiply(m1, m2, m3);
        if(time == 1000) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (time > 1000) {

            m1 = createFilledSquareMatrix(mid-1);
            m2 = createFilledSquareMatrix(mid-1);
            m3 = new double[mid-1][mid-1];
            time = analyzeMultiply(m1, m2, m3);
            if(time <= 1000) {
                return mid;  //I am reached but ignored
            }
            else {
                binarySearch(min, mid-1);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("here");
            m1 = createFilledSquareMatrix(mid+1);
            m2 = createFilledSquareMatrix(mid+1);
            m3 = new double[mid+1][mid+1];
            time = analyzeMultiply(m1, m2, m3);
            if(time >= 1000) {
                return mid+1; //I am reached but ignored
            }
            else {
                binarySearch(mid+1, max);
            }
        }

    return -2;

}
```

So I have commented the return statements that are ignored. I go through with the debugger and it executes the return but then just goes to the outter return -2 statement and then executes that. I've never had this type of issue before so I feel like I am missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is recursive. This means that every time you recurse, you need to do something with the returned value from the recursive call. What you are seeing is that the recursive calls reach a termination point, return a value, and then bubble back out. However since the instance that made the recursive call doesn't do anything with the returned value, it continues executing as if nothing happened, causing it to drop back to it's "catch all" return instead, and so on.

For example,

```
  else {
            binarySearch(min, mid-1);
        }
```

should be

```
   else {
            return binarySearch(min, mid-1);
        }
```